# Certain Strategy Pattern cases violating Liskov’s substitution principle?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I know a similar question has been asked, but it doesn’t describe the same problem I am facing.

According to the Head First Design Patterns book, the Strategy Pattern can be used to extract the fly behavior out of the Duck classes.

[image]

However, in one of Uncle Bob’s lectures I heard this for Liskov’s substitution principle:

> Derived classes should not violate the expectations the users of the parent class have of it.

Isn’t the users expectation for the duck to fly when they call the fly function? For there to be some change in its state (x and y coords for example)?

Uncle Bob’s example was the rectangle-square problem, in which a derived Square class (from Rectangle base class) has a function setWidth which sets both the width AND height.

I see these two examples as being similar, and wonder why it is acceptable in the duck case? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strategy Pattern violating Liskov's substitution principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287085/strategy-pattern-violating-liskovs-substitution-principle)

Comment: Linked example is identical to the point of also using ducks.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. We are both using ducks because we're basing our questions on the "Head First Design Patterns" book which provided that example. I saw that post already and it doesn't satisfy me for multiple reasons. It does not offer a concrete response to whether the principle is violated or not. Also, I feel most people in that discussion don't have the same understanding of it, which is why I provided additional context to my question

Comment: The square example is more detailed and it's easy to see the violation of an expectation. Your assumption could be true about x an y but you're going to have to go into detail to get an answer. I suspect that once you provide the details the answer will be obvious. With design pattern questions, you have to go into detail because the patterns themselves are "half baked" and the answers tend to be "it depends."

Comment: The proposed duplicate is asking a different question. I think this one is closer to the [Difference between the IS-A and Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45952008/1371329) Also see: [Is this precondition a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61780911/1371329)

Comment: @Fuhrmanator yea that may be true, but I think at this point I was looking for like a general rule that I could apply.

Comment: @jaco0646 Thank you for the good links! Second one has a lot of info, but I think I need a bit more time to fully understand it

Answer (score 0):

Strategy patterns can certainly be *used* to break Liskov substitutability. That's not an argument against them. You can break OOP in pretty much any OO programming language. Just throwing in the equivalent of `exit(0)` will tend to do that. So, the possibility for abuse does not say much.

As for the specific example, it's definitely possible to have *at the same time* some birds that use a FlyBehavior StrategyPattern, and other derived classes that are rather specific and have a direct, non-pattern implementation. So this isn't even a binary choice.

Comment: Could you please explain how to achieve what you've described in your second paragraph? If I understood correctly, some derived Duck classes wouldn't have a flyBehavior property at all, while others do? I think I saw some ways of doing this, for example having only some ducks implement a ICanFly interface, but I never really understood how this can work with composition